# How to correctly type sqlalchemy models to be used together with pydantic?

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-typing, pydantic

I have this UserPydantic model

```py
class UserPydantic(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    name: str = Field(...)
    email: str = EmailStr()
    is_active: bool = Field(default=True)
    is_admin: bool = Field(default=False)
    created_at: datetime = Field(...)
```

And I have this Base:

```py
class UserDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    email = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(length=255), nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=current_timestamp(), nullable=False)
    instagram_dms: Mapped[list["InstagramDmDB"]] = relationship("InstagramDmDB",       
    back_populates="user")

    def to_pydantic(self) -> UserPydantic:
        return UserPydantic(
            name=self.name,
            email=self.email,
            is_active=self.is_active,
            is_admin=self.is_admin,
            created_at=self.created_at
        )
```

However, the issue I am having is with the `to_pydantic` function, where `UserPydantic` expects name to be string but `self.name` is `Column[str]`. This is causing problems down the line as wherever I use the UserDB class my code is expected type `Column[str]` for the fields even if I am returning a `.first()` or `.one()`. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if there is a different/better way to do these things.

This is causing extra problems with my `mypy` tox testing.

Comment: `class Config` was removed in pydantic 2.0 and replaced with ConfigDict and `model_config`. Since you're using `from_attributes`, I guess you're using 2.0 - so `model_config` is the way to go: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_config (the setting was named `orm_mode` in pydantic v1). There is no need to have a dedicated `to_pydantic` function

Comment: @MatsLindh
So I guess my issue is not with pydantic but rather with sqlalchemy:

For example
```
@user_router.put("/change-password")
async def change_password(current_password: str, new_password: str, current_user: UserDB = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    with get_db() as db:
        user = authenticate_user(current_user.email, current_password, db)
```
the problem is, current_user.email is typed Column[str] even though get_current returns a .first(). I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: _What_ is giving you this error? Your IDE? The Python interpreter? Pydantic? ruff? black?

Comment: If it's mypy that's yielding errors, I would recommend using the new [declarative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping) interface introduced in SQLAlchemy 2.0. It is more or less type safe.

Comment: @MatsLindh its both the IDE (VSCode) that is typing it as Column[str] and mypy in my tox test thats resulting in invalid.

Comment: @M.O. This worked, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

using the new [declarative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping) interface introduced in SQLAlchemy 2.0. It is more or less type safe.
@M.O.

Comment: please consider a full anwer with a code example, @zachatoch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).